# "numpy.interp" ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, interpolation

I have a data set that has one set of x values and many sets of y values that have the same set of x values. For instance,

```
X     Y2     Y3
0     2     1     
2     4     15
4     7     20
6     4     30
8     5     10
10     0.2     1 
12     0.7     2
14     1     1
16     1.2     10
18     2.4     11
20     2.5     5
22     3     6
24     1     7
26     8     7
28     9     5
30     1     1.2
32     1.2     1.5
34     1.5     2
```

I want to get Y2 and Y3 values for "`new_x`" by using interpolation.
`new_x=np.arange(0,34,0.424)`.

```
array([ 0.   ,  0.424,  0.848,  1.272,  1.696,  2.12 ,  2.544,  2.968,
        3.392,  3.816,  4.24 ,  4.664,  5.088,  5.512,  5.936,  6.36 ,
        6.784,  7.208,  7.632,  8.056,  8.48 ,  8.904,  9.328,  9.752,
       10.176, 10.6  , 11.024, 11.448, 11.872, 12.296, 12.72 , 13.144,
       13.568, 13.992, 14.416, 14.84 , 15.264, 15.688, 16.112, 16.536,
       16.96 , 17.384, 17.808, 18.232, 18.656, 19.08 , 19.504, 19.928,
       20.352, 20.776, 21.2  , 21.624, 22.048, 22.472, 22.896, 23.32 ,
       23.744, 24.168, 24.592, 25.016, 25.44 , 25.864, 26.288, 26.712,
       27.136, 27.56 , 27.984, 28.408, 28.832, 29.256, 29.68 , 30.104,
       30.528, 30.952, 31.376, 31.8  , 32.224, 32.648, 33.072, 33.496,
       33.92 ])
```

When I run `intrp_CC=np.interp(new_x,old_x,current_Y)`, I get `ValueError: object too deep for desired array`.

Any idea as to why this is happening and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you read the docs?

> Returns the one-dimensional piecewise linear interpolant to a function
>   with given discrete data points (`xp`, `fp`), evaluated at `x`.
>
> fp : 1-D sequence of float or complex

With a 1d `fp`:

```
In [397]: np.interp(np.arange(10), np.arange(10), np.arange(20).reshape(2,10)[0,:])
Out[397]: array([0., 1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9.])
```

With a 2d, multirow, `fp` - your error:

```
In [398]: np.interp(np.arange(10), np.arange(10), np.arange(20).reshape(2,10))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-398-e1383ba2f0f0> in <module>()
----> 1 np.interp(np.arange(10), np.arange(10), np.arange(20).reshape(2,10))

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in interp(x, xp, fp, left, right, period)
   1306         fp = np.concatenate((fp[-1:], fp, fp[0:1]))
   1307 
-> 1308     return interp_func(x, xp, fp, left, right)
   1309 
   1310 

ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Comment: My bad. What I end up having to do is to create a for loop to do interpolate one y for one x for all sets of y values.

Answer (score 1):

I think that it is still a fair question to ask if the explicit for loop is in any way avoidable..... The answer to that question is yes, provided one uses scipy interpolate.interp1d module instead of numpy.