Python: ValueError: object too deep for desired array. How do I fix this?
VScode show an error on line 12 and 22. Here is the code.
from scipy.io import wavfile
import numpy as np

def change_pitch(input_file, output_file, semitones, nsemitones):
    # Read the .wav file
    sample_rate, data = wavfile.read(input_file)
    
    # Define the pitch shift factor
    pitch_factor = 2 ** (semitones / nsemitones)
    
    # Apply pitch shift
    shifted_data = np.interp( np.arange(0, len(data), pitch_factor),np.arange(0, len(data)),data).astype(data.dtype)
    
    # Write the modified data to a new .wav file
    wavfile.write(output_file, sample_rate, shifted_data)

#Test usage
input_file = "rhodes.wav"
output_file = "output.wav"
semitones_to_change = 10  # Change this value according to your requirement
nsemitones = 12
change_pitch(input_file, output_file, semitones_to_change, nsemitones)

here are the errors:
 File "C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Bureau\useless fucking MIDi\python.py", line 12, in change_pitch
    shifted_data = np.interp( np.arange(0, len(data), pitch_factor),np.arange(0, len(data)),data).astype(data.dtype)
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
line 22, in <module>
    change_pitch(input_file, output_file, semitones_to_change, nsemitones)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array

I want to change the frequency of 'rhodes.wav' into a c4 instead of a d3

Check the args to interp, and read its docs.  One (or more) is multidimensional when it shouldn't be.  Or wrong dtype.  What is data.dtype?  While you at it, show us that information.  We can't deduce that stuff from your files or code.

I answered a similar question 5 years ago.  Did you search SO for such an error message? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53621555/numpy-interp-valueerror-object-too-deep-for-desired-array

What is data?  shape?  dtype?

If the wav file has more than one channel, data will be a 2-d array.  np.interp does not accept 2-d arrays in the fp argument.  See the question that @hpaulj linked to for more information, including the suggestion to try scipy.interpolate.interp1d instead of np.interp.

@hpaulj data.dtype is int16 and shape is (392913, 2), hope this helps

@WarrenWeckesser How do you check how many channels the wavefile has? And how do you make it so that it only has one?

@hpaulj Sorry for being late, I was asleep

@WarrenWeckesser scipy.interpolate.interp1d didn't work, sadly

author here. The wav file had too many channels. You need to convert from stereo to mono, or make one for every channel. To convert from stereo to mono, you need to add this code after line 6.
if len(data.shape) > 1:
    data = data.mean(axis=1)

However, if you want to shift for every channel, you need to make a for i in range[1,len(data)] loop, then merge them using
import wave
def combine_wav_files(output_file, input_files):
with wave.open(input_files[0],'rb') as wave_file:
    params = wave_file.getparams()
with wave.open(output_file[0],'wb') as wave_file:
    params = output.setparams(params)
    for file in input_files:
        with wave.open(file, 'rb') as wave_file:
            data = wave_file.readframes(wave_file.getnframes)
            output.writeframes(data)

I hope this helps.
