3d array operations in numpy
I have two numpy arrays (say A and B). A with shape  - (20,5,5) and B - (20,).  Array B has increasing int values ​​in range [0, 8] with some repeated numbers (but ascending).
Array A:
array([[[  1,   2,   3,   4,   5],
        [  6,   7,   8,   9,  10],
        [ 11,  12,  13,  14,  15],
        [ 16,  17,  18,  19,  20],
        [ 21,  22,  23,  24,  25]],

       [[ 26,  27,  28,  29,  30],
        [ 31,  32,  33,  34,  35],
        [ 36,  37,  38,  39,  40],
        [ 41,  42,  43,  44,  45],
        [ 46,  47,  48,  49,  50]],

Array B (some value are repeating):
array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8])

I need to calculate a 3D array C that will have the same x and y shape (3, 5,5) as A, but the first dimension index should be values ​​from array B, but downsampled to 4 ( 0, 4, 8). I don't understand how can I do this with Numpy.

    import numpy as np
    z = 20
    x = 5
    y = 5
    
    # Array A
    A = np.arange(1, 501,1)
    A = A.reshape(z, x, y)
    print ("A.shape = {}".format(A.shape)) # (20, 5, 5)
    
    # Array B
    B = np.arange(0, 12, 1)
    B = np.repeat(B, 3)
    B = B[[2,3,4,6,7,8,9,10,12,13,15,16,17,20,21,22,23,24,25,26]]
    print ("B.shape = {}".format(B.shape)) # (20,)
    print ("Array B = {}".format(B)) # array([0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8])
    
    # Sampling by 4
    t = np.arange(0, 12, 4)
    print ("Sampling by 4 = {}".format(t)) # array([0, 4, 8])



In this case C.shape should be (3,5,5)
A[17,0,0] = 426, A[18,0,0] = 451, A[19,0,0] = 476
C[2,0,0] = np.mean([A[17,0,0],A[18,0,0],A[19,0,0]]) # ideally to apply low pass filtering (which is a sort of averaging)
I tried to draw my question for clarity - 

Look up that too deep error in other SO.  I think it has to do with A being 3d, while B is only 1d.   For now I'm not trying to follow what you are doing with this down-sampling.

What is the relationship between arrays A and B?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53622037/901925

@jared Indices of first dimension in A and B are the same.

@explorer_7 Yes, but what do the values mean? How are they related to one another?

Sorry @jared I didn't get your question. Basically what I want is to take the values of array B based on the same indices between A and B and use these values from B as indices in first dimension of C but the values should be from A. Hope it is clear.

Did you pay attention to the 'see also' for np.interp?  scipy.interpolate

@explorer_7, your problem statement makes no sense at all: what does ‘take the values of array B based on the same indices between A and B and use these values from B as indices in first dimension of C but the values should be from A’ mean? Are you sure that you have correctly translated the word “indices”?

@lastchance I mean the value of for example B[50] (eg B[50]= 42) should be the index of C, so C[42, 2,2] == A[50,2,2]

So if C is zeros of the right size C[B[i]] = A[i] for all i.  What about duplicates in B?  Use the last one?  Sum?

It might be Mean value.

Can you show, what result do you want, because I really don't understand what you try to achieve. Just, use toy example arrays with little size (8, 1, 1) or something like this.

I draw a sketch to explain my question - please have a look at the end of question post.

@BogdanShevchenko - https://i.sstatic.net/yr5zQwb0.png

In this picture it looks like you need just correct indexing? I mean, am I understand correct: firstly you turn B into B[::4] ([B[0], B[4], B[8], ....., B[220]] in your example), and than just index A with it? A[B[::4].astype(int)] something like this?

@BogdanShevchenko thanks for your time. If I do B[::4] then I get values [0,1,3,4,6..... ] what I need is B = [0,4,8,12,16...} like in t (shown on the image).

If you just need the "values" 0, 4, 8, 12, 16, ... why do you need B at all? B[::4] will give you the "values" B[0], B[4], B[8], B[12], B[16], .... which seems to be what you wanted?

I have the same question as @lastchance, I don't understand what is the role of B. If you want [0, 4, 8, ...] you can simply use A[slice(0, len(A), 4)], without B at all.

can you explicitely describe structure of C:
C[0] = A[?];
C[1] = A[?];
C[2] = A[?];
....;
C[56?] = A[?]
And what is 56? If last number in B is not 220, will shape of C be different?

Let me try to explain. I need B array, because array B is the connection between A and C. Index of B and first index of A are the same - 0,1,2,..511. What I need in C is the value from A - second and third indices for both arrays are the same, but the 1st index of C should be values (not indices) from B, but regurarly sampled - 0,4,8....which as index will be 0,1,2,3 ...and the value for C array will be the corresponding (average?) value from A. Like C[0, x,y] = A[0,x,y], C[1, x,y] = A[10? or11? or12?,x,y].because B[10] = 4,B[11] = 4 and B[12]=4. C[56,x,y] = A[510? 511?,x, y]. Is it clear now?

No, it isn't clear. It is even more obscure than before. Just create a small matrix A, a small array B and give the actual array C that you want as a result. "Small" does not mean 256x256. It means small enough to write down every single member of. Do it in your post, so that it can be well-formatted - not in a comment.

Thank you for this example it shows clearly that every my idea of what exactly your code should do is wrong. Can you explain, why C[2,0,0] = np.mean([A[17,0,0],A[18,0,0],A[19,0,0]]) ? Why 17, 18, 19? And also, why C.shape[0] = 3?

Or, can I make another theory:
Is it true that
C[0,0,0] = np.mean([A[0,0,0],A[1,0,0],A[2,0,0],A[3,0,0],A[4,0,0],A[5,0,0],A[6,0,0],A[7,0,0]])

@explorer_7, have you now abandoned your original requirement that B[] contained floats?

@BogdanShevchenko Can you explain, why C[2,0,0] = np.mean([A[17,0,0],A[18,0,0],A[19,0,0]]) ? Why 17, 18, 19? Because the B[17] B[18} and B[19] are all = 8. And 8 should correspond to the 2 index in C (first dimension), because 0->0, 4->1 and 8->2. Does it make sence?

@lastchance yes I converted them to integers, no more float values.

@BogdanShevchenko your theory is correct, but other way around, for C[0.0.0] = A[0.0.0] but for C[1.0.0] = np.mean(A[1,0,0],A[2,0,0],A[3,0,0],A[4,0,0],A[5,0,0],A[6,0,0],A[7,0,0] ...) - values between 0 and 4. So it is my mistake  in picture and explanation for the 8th one, it should be mean between 5 and 8.

Start with a simple case where A is ONE-DIMENSIONAL and hard-wire everything:
import numpy as np
A = np.array( [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 ], dtype=float )
B = np.array( [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 4,  6,  6,  8,  8,  8 ] )
C = np.zeros( 3 )
C[0] = np.mean( A[B==0] )
C[1] = np.mean( A[B==4] )
C[2] = np.mean( A[B==8] )
print( C )

This gives:
[ 1.  8. 17.]

Then your general case: A is 3-dimensional, you need to deduce dimensions and deal quietly with the case where a specific value isn't found in B (I've set the relevant plate of C to all zeros in this case).
I've set the extraction criterion to B==4*i. I don't understand all your explanations (and I think they have changed over multiple edits), so you can adjust the extraction/averaging criterion if you wish, including a range of values (1-4, 5-8, 9-12, ...) if you prefer.
import numpy as np
A = np.array( [ 
                [ [   1,   2,   3 ], [   4,   5,   6 ], [   7,   8,   9 ] ],
                [ [  11,  12,  13 ], [  14,  15,  16 ], [  17,  18,  19 ] ],
                [ [  21,  22,  23 ], [  24,  25,  26 ], [  27,  28,  29 ] ],
                [ [  31,  32,  33 ], [  34,  35,  36 ], [  37,  38,  39 ] ],
                [ [  41,  42,  43 ], [  44,  45,  46 ], [  47,  48,  49 ] ],
                [ [  51,  52,  53 ], [  54,  55,  56 ], [  57,  58,  59 ] ],
                [ [  61,  62,  63 ], [  64,  65,  66 ], [  67,  68,  69 ] ],
                [ [  71,  72,  73 ], [  74,  75,  76 ], [  77,  78,  79 ] ],
                [ [  81,  82,  83 ], [  84,  85,  86 ], [  87,  88,  89 ] ],
                [ [  91,  92,  93 ], [  94,  95,  96 ], [  97,  98,  99 ] ]
              ] )

B = np.array( [ 0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 8, 8, 8 ] )

N = 1 + B[-1] // 4;           print( "Reduced N = ", N, "\n" )
x, y, z = np.shape( A )
C = np.zeros( ( N, y, z ) )
for i in range( 0, N ):
    criterion = ( B == 4 * i )         # Adjust this to whatever you want
    if np.any( criterion ): C[i] = np.mean( A[criterion], axis=0 )

print( C )

Output:
Reduced N =  3

[[[ 1.  2.  3.]
  [ 4.  5.  6.]
  [ 7.  8.  9.]]

 [[36. 37. 38.]
  [39. 40. 41.]
  [42. 43. 44.]]

 [[81. 82. 83.]
  [84. 85. 86.]
  [87. 88. 89.]]]


I think, I finally understand what you want to obtain:
z = 20
x = 5
y = 5

A = np.arange(x * y * z).reshape(z, x, y)
B = np.array([0., 1., 1.1, 2., 2., 2., 3., 3.5, 4., 4., 
              5., 5., 5., 6., 7., 7., 7.9, 8., 8., 8.])
# it will work the same for float and int B
B_ind = np.ceil(B / 4).astype(int)
# B_ind = [0] * 1 + [1] * 9 + [2] * 10
# We need to make C so that
# C[0] = A[0] # 1 layer averaged
# C[1] = A[1:10].mean(axis=0) # 9 layers averaged
# C[2] = A[11:].mean(axis=0)  # 10 layers averaged
num_change_indexes = np.unique(B_ind, return_index=True)[1]
# num_change_indexes=[0, 1, 10]

C = np.zeros((B_ind[-1] + 1, x, y))  #3, 5, 5
for ind, A_chunk in zip(
    num_change_indexes, 
    np.split(A, num_change_indexes[1:])
): 
    # numpy doesn't have native groupby, 
    # but you can use other libs for it, 
    # if you want to avoid this loop
    C[B_ind[ind]] = A_chunk.mean(axis=0)

also, I am not sure with your float to int conversion: I mean, if B[N] = 0.5, will A[N] go to C[0] or to C[1]?
If you at first make float to int conversion and after that divide by four and take ceil, it will of to C[0], but if you divide, ceil and convert to int at the end – it will go to C[1] group, order meters. I use second approach, if you want to use first, change B_ind calculations to
B_ind = np.ceil(B.astype(int) / 4).astype(int)
